# VBA Excel/Word Find and Replace

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm developing an Excel sheet to search in a Word document for a specific instance (Column A) and replace them by the instance in cell B.

I want to change only the first instance that matches the search criteria, and keep looping trough the column to the next instances.

I've written the code below.

If I use "wdReplaceAll" it replaces all the specific instance in the Word document.
If I use wdReplaceOne" the code will break after the first change.

VBA Code:

```
Sub Replace()

Dim pathh As String
Dim pathhi As String
Dim oCell  As Integer
Dim from_text As String, to_text As String
Dim WA As Object

pathh = "C:\Users\Rui.Fernandes\Arquivo Rui Fernandes\On.me Documentação\Construção\Documentos Obra Tipo\PGC.10.Ed.1 - Auditorias Internas.doc"

Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WA.Documents.Open (pathh)
WA.Visible = True

For oCell = 1 To 10
    from_text = Sheets("PTAct").Range("A" & oCell).Value
    to_text = Sheets("PTAct").Range("B" & oCell).Value
    With WA
        .Activate
    With .Selection.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting

      .Text = from_text
      .Replacement.Text = to_text
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End With
Next oCell

End sub
```

How can I do make it do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do late binding, so wdReplaceAll and wdReplaceOne will not be what you expect. Look in Word VBA help for the WdReplace Enumeration and its values.

```
Sub Replace()

Dim pathh As String
Dim pathhi As String
Dim oCell  As Integer
Dim from_text As String, to_text As String
Dim WA As Object

pathh = "C:\Users\axel\Documents\replacetest.docx"

Set WA = CreateObject("Word.Application")
WA.Documents.Open (pathh)
WA.Visible = True

For oCell = 1 To 10
    from_text = Sheets("PTAct").Range("A" & oCell).Value
    to_text = Sheets("PTAct").Range("B" & oCell).Value
    With WA.ActiveDocument
        Set myRange = .Content
        With myRange.Find
            .Execute FindText:=from_text, ReplaceWith:=to_text, Replace:=1
        End With
    End With
Next oCell

End Sub
```

Greetings

Axel